# How to get WebElement Button by label

Tags: java, selenium, button, label

I work on a Java project where I have to do some UATs with Selenium.
I have no knowledge about Webdevelopment so I am not sure if my problem can be solved.
The problem is:
There is a Webpage in which you can tick some Radio Buttons or Checkboxes. All of them have a field right next to them with a text. So I want to find those buttons and checkboxes with Java and Selenium to tick them. With Firefox I opened the console to get the code of some Buttons:

```
<tr>
<td class="af_tableSelectMany_cell-icon-format OraTableBorder1111" style="">
<input id="equipmentChecker6" type="checkbox" onchange="setDirty();deselectOptions('6');selectOption('6');" value="true" name="equipmentChecker6">
</td>
<td class="af_column_cell-text OraTableBorder1111" style="text-align: left; ">Some Text1</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td class="af_column_cell-text OraTableBorder1111"> </td>
<td class="af_column_cell-text OraTableBorder1111" style="text-align: left;">
<span class="af_selectOneRadio">
<span id="optionRadio5" class="af_selectOneRadio_content">
<input id="optionRadio5:_0" type="radio" onchange="setDirty();selectEquipment('5');" value="0" name="optionRadio5">
<label for="optionRadio5:_0">Some Text2</label>
</span>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

this is some code from the Page. Now I want to get the Webelement with the id=equipmentChecker6 but I just have the text "Some Text1".

In the second example I want to get the id=optionRadio5:_0 by just having the Text "Some Text2" of the label object.
Is there a way to get the button elements as Webelements in Java with Selenium?

thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
// For the first case
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Some Text1']/preceding-sibling::td/input[@type='checkbox']")).click();

// For the second case
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Some Text2']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='radio']")).click();
```

Comment: thanks that worked! Is there a doc where I can find an explanation of this method so I can solve future similar problems by my own?

Comment: Actually it's common `XPath` syntax. `preceding-sibling` as well as `following-sibling` allow you to handle previous/next element on the same level in `DOM`. I'd suggest you to put this https://www.simple-talk.com/wp-content/uploads/imported/1269-Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf to your browser bookmark if you're going to work a lot with `selenium` and locators: there is a lot about `XPath` and `CSS` selectors

Comment: thank yout! what about this example:

`<tr>
 <td class="af_tableSelectOne_cell-icon-format OraTableBorder1111">
  <input id="j_id_1r_1_72_3_1:0" type="radio" checked="" value="0" onclick="setDirty();" title="" name="j_id_1r_1_72_3_1:selected">
  <label class="p_OraHiddenLabel" for="j_id_1r_1_72_3_1:0"></label>
 </td>
 <td class="left-content-text af_column_cell-text OraTableBorder1111">
  <span class="">Some Text</span>
 </td>
 <td class="right-content-text af_column_cell-text OraTableBorder1111">
  <span class="decimalNumberAlign">Some Number</span>
 </td>
</tr>`

Comment: I want to get the radio button by searching via "Some Text" or "Some Number"

Comment: Same scheme: `//td[span[text()="Some Text"]]/preceding-sibling::td/input`

Comment: this helped me a lot! Is there a way to do logical conjunction? For example in my previous code snippet:
I want to get the radio Button where it has on the same level a field "Some Number" AND "Some Text"

Comment: Ooook... :) You can use "parent for all" element - `<tr>` like this : `tr[td[span[text()="Some Number"]] and td[span[text()="Some Text"]]]/td/input`

Answer (score 0):

https://loadfocus.com/blog/2013/09/05/how-to-locate-web-elements-with-selenium-webdriver/

driver.findElement(By.id("element id"))

so in this case:

driver.findElement(By.id("equipmentChecker6 "))

Comment: this would work but I dont know about the id. The scenario is: there is someone defining the parameters and the parameters are the labels. So I just have the labels to find the Buttons they refer to.